# Selecting column data from SQL ordered inside while loop

Tags: php, sql

I have a database like this

```
|| ID    -     COL1   - COL2||
|| 1     -    row1A  -  1  ||
|| 2     -    row1A  -  1  ||
|| 3     -    row1A  -  2  ||
|| 4     -    row1B  -  2  ||
|| 5     -    row1A  -  3  ||
|| 6     -    row1B  -  3  ||
```

i want to `ECHO` these data like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE COL1 = 'row1A'";
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $col = $row['COL1'];
    echo "
     <div>Set1: $col</div> // = row1A, row1A  as where COL2 = 1
     <div>Set2: $col</div> // = row1A as where COL2 = 2
     <div>Set3: $col</div> // = row1A as where COL2 = 3
    ";
}
```

I'm using this with a relation between 3 tables so each row1A will has its own name in different table, But right now i want to know how can i call the database ordered by `COL2`

**For each `SetN` gets the value of `COL1 WHERE COL2` = `N`**

Comment: Just add: `ORDER BY col2 ASC` in your SQL query. You can use `DESC` for descending order.

Comment: Tried ORDER BY COL2 ?

Comment: @Duvdevan If i did that, The query would be ordered But I'll get two times the `Set1`: `Set2`: `Set3`:, I want each `Set ` to have its number's row, for `Set1` gets all `COL1` values WHERE `COL2 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` in sql. Please check following code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE COL1 = 'row1A' ORDER BY COL2 ASC";
```

Comment: Would that put for each `SetN` the value of `COL1` where `COL2` = N?

Answer (score 0):

You can ORDER any data in SQL Query by COLUMN with

> ORDER BY

Like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE COL1 = 'row1A' ORDER BY COL2 DESC (or ASC)";
```

Comment: That would give me all the database sets with 'row1A' ordered, But i want for each `SetN` to get the value of `COL1` where COL2 = N

Comment: Maybe you are looking for SELECT DISTINCT COL2

Comment: Or GROUP BY statement

Comment: the `row1A` values aren't always the same And each value is unique

Comment: GROUP BY works in columns only, i guess, I want to order by  col row value